# Use Driver 2.0 in Unwind operation

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, fluent

Using MongoDB C# Driver 2.0 fluent API for Aggregate with Unwind operator, the reference documentation (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/#unwind) instructs to use the following

> An $unwind stage is defined using the Unwind method and its overloads.
>   Because $unwind is a type of projection, you must provide a return
>   type.

Unfortunately it does not say how you should provide the type.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It also says __"An $unwind stage is defined using the Unwind method and its overloads. Because $unwind is a type of projection, you must provide a return type, although not specifying one will use the overload that projects into a BsonDocument."__ Take a look at the API documentation and that might clear it up http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluent_1_Unwind__1.htm

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes a little "look one more time..." works...